# Understanding Batch For /D Loop Copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, copy

I'm stuck with an idea that I just can't get off the ground and it's because I don't understand FOR loops very well.

Essentially though, what I am trying to do is a FOR loop that will go through its current directory and for every folder that is 7 random numbers long, it'll move another file into that directory and call it. I'll make a diagram here.

- %cd%

  - \1234567\
  - \2345671\
  - \3456712\
  - \Release\
  - filetomove.bat

So the intent is that the file to move will end up only in the numbered directories.

- %cd%

  - \1234567\filetomove.bat
  - \2345671\filetomove.bat
  - \3456712\filetomove.bat
  - \Release\
  - filetomove.bat

Then once it is in those directories, it will call the bat in each of them.

- %cd%

  - CALL \1234567\filetomove.bat
  - CALL \2345671\filetomove.bat
  - CALL \3456712\filetomove.bat
  - \Release\
  - filetomove.bat

I would make it more convoluted with an IF statement to only move a certain .bat if certain files are or aren't present, but I want to be able to get down moving the file first. I think I might be good on the IF statement.

Does anyone know what the heck I'd want to do to make this possible? I thought for file directories I could have done like

```
FOR /D %%G in ("%cd%\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\") DO COPY...
```

but apparently something like this doesn't work the way I intend. The only way I could actually see that's finding each file is to do something like...

```
FOR /D %%G in ("%cd%\*") DO ECHO %%G
```

and have the code return to me the directories string. What am I doing wrong, just don't know, or just am not understanding?

Comment: Windows command line doesn't do regular expressions, so `[0-9]` is a no-go. You'll need to use `findstr` which does understand regexes.

Comment: Would this be going in the right direction?

`FOR /D %%G in (findstr...) DO COPY...`

Comment: There are soooo many pitfalls here. Check out the answer. I'll add to it to explain the weirdest parts.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `filetomove.bat` the same file and you're making copies so that each copy can run in that particular directory? If so, I can show you how to run it that way without making copies of the .bat file.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm trying to get it in all of those locations. My process is a bit like this
- Get done with current work. Work results in a very cluttered up mess consisting of .pdf, .dwg, and .xlsx files.
- Copy a script that will when in the directory I was working in, move all of these files into a number of directories for file upload and sync to a server.

Since the folders I work in are all 7 digit long folders of variable numbers, I figured a loop that will copy this script into each directory then call it automatically would be best but it's turning out to be difficult.

Comment: [Image of attempting code](http://imgur.com/a/tIpLH)

Still having trouble here. I figured I'd show you my screen to show exactly what I'm working with here.

Comment: What's in `CleanUp.bat`, and can you make changes to it so that it's more useful here? Also, can you describe "trouble"? Without seeing output or knowing what `CleanUp.bat` does, I can't really provide any useful help.

Comment: Yeah I'll link you to clean up. [link](http://pastebin.com/jiyuejr9)

It does a number of things, but it will always make a directory even if it has nothing to move. [Link](http://pastebin.com/e5VJm3NX) what I've currently got with your help. I thought I'd try to make it just make a directory called TEST before it popd's. Doesn't seem to be doing that either but for a while it was making a %%a BACKUP directory in the 1 Working folder. Not in any of the numbered folders.

Comment: i THINK WE'VE GOT IT AND IT WAS ME BEING AN IDIOT WITH YOUR CODE, I'M SO SORRY FOR KEEPING YOU UP TONIGHT. [code here](http://pastebin.com/SfVARr2Y) worked. I was attempting to run the code through N++ and didn't realize N++ was not actually updating the file or really running the code. Thank you so much though, I'm going to really need to find more ways to use FOR loops but I can think of many things with what you provided. I appreciate your help so much! Is there anything I could give you for your time and trouble? Reddit Gold? Something?

Comment: You could vote for my solution :) I accumulated a bunch of batch knowledge from my last job. Luckily I don't have to use it much in my current position, but it makes me feel better if I can pretend I didn't waste weeks of my life pulling my hair out to learn it the hard way just to end up in a job where it's unnecessary.

Comment: I don't have the minimum reputation of 15 for my vote to seem to mean anything u_u But I'll have to revisit this when I have that much rep. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding your entire idea, but here's how you can iterate over all the folders that have 7 digit names and then run batch's equivalent of a function to handle the output. Note that to use the `%%` variable syntax this needs to be run from inside a batch file. The command line uses only a single `%` in front of the iterator variable.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /aD * ^|findstr /R "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"') do call :junk "%%a"
REM stuff here runs after the for loop finishes

REM the goto :EOF here makes sure we aren't going to accidentally run :junk again when we didn't mean to.
goto :EOF
:junk
REM This runs each time 'for' spits out a new directory name.
set yourDirName=%~1
REM do other stuff here with this dir name, like copying or whatever.

REM If for instance you wanted to run a batch file c:\mybatfile.bat in
REM  each dir, you could do that here:
pushd "%yourDirName%"
REM Now you're in the %yourDirName% directory and you can run your command:
c:\mybatfile.bat
popd
REM popd is the opposite of pushd.
goto :EOF
```

Here's an explanation of some of the syntax in the order it's used in the script.

`for /f` can parse command output. That's why it's always my favorite.

`"tokens=*"` causes the output from that iteration of the for-loop to all end up in one variable (`%%a`). Otherwise you would get the first delimited token in %%a, the next in %%b, etc.

Single-quote your command. I do it because it works, not because I know why.

For `dir` `/b` removes the columns of info you don't need and just gives the name. `/aD` gives you the files that have the `D`irectory `/a`ttribute

You need to escape the `|` character with a `^` when it's part of a command you're giving to `for`

Use `findstr /R` so you can filter the names based on a regular expression.

`call` allows you to jump to a block of commands and pass arguments to that block (as %1, %2, etc.) so you can execute a set of commands without having to cram them into a set of parentheses since that gives you weird evaluation  behavior.

When you use `call`, it's like running another script that just happens to be part of your current script. To return from that "other script"'s execution context, you use `goto :EOF`. It's distinct from `exit` because it doesn't completely terminate your program; it just does a `goto` on the meta-label `:EOF` which is short for End-Of-File. Here we want the script to act as if it has run out of commands (where it will keep executing a higher context if there was one) rather than exiting all the way out to the command line using `exit`.
The flow here is:

Start at the `for` loop

For each iteration of the `for` loop:

`call :junk`

Execute all of the commands under `:junk` until we hit the `goto :EOF`

`goto :EOF` at the bottom of `:junk` causes execution control to return to the `for` loop so it can iterate again.

When the `for` runs out of data to iterate over, it tries to execute more lines of the script. We don't want it to execute `:junk` again, so there's a `goto :EOF` above `:junk`.

Simple, right?

Comment: Very complicated and would have taken me a long time to come   that far with it. Let me attempt working with what was provided. Question though, I notice the GOTO :EOF. Is the first one just to stop the FOR loop then the second to put an end to the rest of my commands being executed?

Comment: It has to do with :call. To avoid cramming the explanation into a comment, I'll add to the answer.